# How can I use regexp-match in order to list all given in Racket

Tags: racket

If I'm given a string of data

```
"data-symbol='1'
 data-symbol='2'
 data-symbol='3'
 data-symbol='4' "
```

How can I take the numbers out of the string using regexp-match and put them into a list
'(1 2 3 4), order isn't necessary. Also as for the numbers they could be anything they're just used as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`regexp-match*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-match%2A%29%29) along with capturing groups and [`string->number`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3enumber%29%29) to extract the information from your string:

```
> (map string->number
       (regexp-match* #px"data-symbol='(\\d+)'"
                      "data-symbol='1'
                       data-symbol='2'
                       data-symbol='3'
                       data-symbol='4'"
                      #:match-select second))
'(1 2 3 4)
```

The [`regexp-match*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-match%2A%29%29) function finds all matches of a regular expression in a given string, and `#:match-select` is used to pick which capture group(s) to return in the result. Then [`string->number`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3enumber%29%29) is used to convert each element of the match to a numeric value.

Be careful, though: it looks like you might be trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, and as was (in)famously noted on this very site, [that way leads only to madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/465378). Consider using one of Racket’s HTML parsing libraries instead.

Comment: Dont worry im not trying to parse html, and I'm very aware of that post lol. Also thanks for the answer